# How to determine if contents of String is Integer, Boolean or Double?

Tags: java, properties

I am currently reading a .properties file in my java project and I noticed every line is read as String (not matter if I use `.get()` or `.getProperty()`). So, I was wondering how can I determine, from the contents of a `String`, if that value is `boolean` or `Integer` or `double` or even a `String`.

```
"asavvvav" --> String
"12345678" --> Integer
"false"    --> Boolean
```

Comment: Ordinarily, one would not attempt what you ask at all.  One would know what form of data was expected for each property name, and parse / validate the associated value against that specific form.

Comment: Note also that you cannot inherently distinguish `Integer`s from `Double`s.  That is, any string that can be interpreted as a decimal `Integer` can also be interpreted as a `Double`.

Comment: You could add type metadata like [bencoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bencode) or just `type:value`.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Java is able to distinguish between them just fine in source code. You just need to have rules about which either of them should look like.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt, The Java compiler recognizes the type of decimal `int` constants as `int` rather than `double` not by anything inherent in the constants themselves, but by an extrinsic rule specifically addressing that matter.  The OP's program could also do so, but it is not at all clear whether it would be useful or appropriate for it to apply a general-purpose rule for the purpose.  If it *were* useful and appropriate, then it would still be unclear whether Java's rules for disambiguating would be the right ones for the OP's purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use regex:

```
String booleanRegex = false|true;
String numberRegex = \\d+;

if(input.matches(booleanRegex)) {

} else if(input.matches(numberRegex)) {

} else {
   //is String
}
```

Or you could attempt to parse and catch the exception:

```
boolean isNumber = false;
try {
    Integer.parseInt(input);
    isNumber = true;
} catch(NumberFormatException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

To check if it's an enum value:

```
try {
    Enum.valueOf(YourEnumType.class, "VALUE");
} catch(IllegalStateException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    //was not enum
}
```

Comment: Cool that works!, But what if I have an enum type? Say there´s an enum called Directions and one of them is NORTH, if "NORTH" is stored in the String, how could I know this is of Enum type Directions?